# Invalid XML in Amazon S3 output caused by object file names

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to copy around 12 million Amazon S3 objects between regions, however around 1.2 million files in it fails due to invalid XML. I get the same issue whether I write a script using AWS PHP SDK, S3cmd or Amazon's command line client.

I suspect the issue is caused by objects that have been uploaded with dodgy file names (ie special characters), as very little/no input sanitisation has been performed.

Regardless I really need to get two buckets in sync between regions so need to find a way to get past this issue.

Has anyone else had this issue, or any advice on how to fix the XML before the client/script reads it so that the process can continue?

Many thanks :)

Comment: "It fails." It might be easier if we had some idea "where" the apparently invalid XML is being generated and appearing (in a response from S3?), and in what sense it is invalid, which component in your stack is declaring it invalid, what's in the original keys that triggers the issue, and the specific (byte level) incorrect values.

Comment: The invalid XML is generated as a result of the command `aws s3 cp s3://usbucket s3://eubucket --recursive`. An example of the returned error is "reference to invalid character number: line 2, column 281556". It's hard to pinpoint the exact key that is triggering the error as it doesn't display that information. If you could let me know a way to produce a more verbose output to be more helpful I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is caused due to S3 generating a key which is different from the file name. It happens if the file names contains characters which is not premitted in URLs.

One way to solve this is to copy **recursively** using the **--recursive** flag in the [S3 CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/). You can point to one root S3 key and ask it to *cp* to another S3 root Key. So CLI takes care of enumerating all file keys and copying.

Comment: Thanks Sony, I will give this solution a try and let you know the result.

Comment: Unfortunately this method causes the same error:

    reference to invalid character number: line 2, column 281556

Original command:

    aws s3 cp s3://usbucket s3://eubucket --recursive